# Check PEP8 in Wing IDE

Tags: python, pep8, wing-ide

I want Wing to PEP8-validate my code.

I found this plugin: [plugin link](http://bitbucket.org/stj/pep8panel/wiki/Home)

I put it in `C:\Users\home\AppData\Roaming\Wing Personal 5\script` directory, opened Wing IDE but nothing appeared.

Is there any way to do PEP8 validating in Wing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That plugin and extension scripts/plugins in general only work in Wing IDE Pro and not Personal.

Answer (score 1):

Did you notice that the windows setting are wrong?

You can look [here](https://bitbucket.org/stj/pep8panel/issue/2/incorrect-instructions-for-windows) to change the arguments.